# Flash Error #1009 on mouse click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, mouseevent

I have a movie clip called AndroidEye2, which has 4 frames.

I have this code on my 'Main Menu' Scene:

```
function eye1(e){
AndroidEye2.gotoAndStop(2);
}

function standStill(e){
AndroidEye2.gotoAndStop(1);
}

ViewMerchandise_IconB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ViewMerchandise1);
function ViewMerchandise1(e) {
gotoAndPlay(1,"ViewMerchandise1");
}

ViewMerchandise_IconB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, eye1);
ViewMerchandise_IconB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, standStill);
```

I have this error

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at Tes_fla::MainTimeline/standStill()

Every time I try to click the ViewMerchandise_IconB button. What did I do wrong?

I'll send you the fla file if you needed to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

The application is complaining about "AndroidEye2.gotoAndStop(1);" It says that AndroidEye2 (that specific instance or static class (depending on what it is)) does not have any property/function called "gotoAndStop". It could also be that AndroidEye2 is null/undefined when that function (`standStill`) is called.

**Edit1:**

```
standStill(e){ 
    trace("instance=" + AndroidEye2); 
    trace("function=" + AndroidEye2.gotoAndStop); 
    AndroidEye2.gotoAndStop(1); 
}
```

Comment: So what should I do for the first problem? Because I've checked that AndroidEye2 is nalready defined when function (standStill) is called.

Comment: You need to find out what is not defined, easiest way is to trace the content when function is called by doing something similar to this:

function standStill(e){

trace("instance=" + AndroidEye2);

trace("function=" + AndroidEye2.gotoAndStop);

AndroidEye2.gotoAndStop(1);
}

Comment: would you like to see my fla? I'm really2 new at this. And I still don't understand what to do.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. You're right, AndroidEye2 is null/undefined when that function (standStill) is called. I figured the mistake. It appears that when I click the 'ViewMerchandise_IconB', the MOUSE_OUT will also run, but I don't have 'AndroidEye2' movie clip on 'ViewMerchandise1' scene.